# Using VB/Python script to populate field with maximum value among other fields

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, vba

I am using ArcGIS 10. I have a little experience with python but i feel that python in ArcGIS is slightly different. VB will work fine as well.

Problem:

I have n different columns called 'percent_1', 'percent_2','percent_3' and 'percent_4'.... 'percent_n'. They contain percentages. I have a new field called 'Class_t'. I want to check which one among 'percent_1..n' is highest and then want to put 'x' in 'Class_t' field.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I'd go python all the way

```
cursor = arcpy.searchcursor(your_table)
for row in cursor:
    sort = sorte([row.percent_1,row.percent_2,row.percent_3,row.percent_4])            
    row.Class_t = sort[len(sort)-1]
    cursor.updateRow(row)
    del row

del cursor
```

Play about with it in Idle, it's something like this.

Answer (score 1):

In python Try to write your fields to a single list and use the max to get the maximum of the fields. Then you may use this max value to update the field you want. I dont have exact same method as your are working but I've a code for writing all the columns in a field to single list then finding the max value from it. Look at the code:

```
import arcpy

workspace = "C:\\Data\\States\States.shp"

fieldlist = arcpy.ListFields(workspace)

List = []

fc = arcpy.SearchCursor(workspace)

Total = 0

for row in fc:
    x = row.getValue("FID")
    List += [x]
    Total += int(x)
rows.next()

print List
print Total
print max(List)
print len(List)
avg = Total/len(List)
print avg
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is exact answer you are looking. Let me know if it solves your problem.

```
import arcpy

workspace = "C:\\Data\\States\States.shp"

fieldlist = arcpy.ListFields(workspace)

#List = []

#fc = arcpy.SearchCursor(workspace)
fc = arcpy.UpdateCursor(workspace)
Total = 0

for row in fc:
    a = int(row.getValue("FID"))
    b = int(row.getValue("Region"))
    c = int(row.getValue("Division"))
    d = int(row.getValue("STATEFP"))
    List = [a,b,c,d]
    print List
    e = max(List)
    print e
    row.Max = e
    fc.updateRow(row)
fc.next()
```